# JavaFX - Set Different Backgrounds for contents of Different TextArea

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm a newbie in JavaFX. How to set different background colors for the contents of different `TextArea`s. As far as I know , using CSS, I can set background color like

```css
.text-area {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-box-border: gray;
}

.text-area .scroll-pane .content{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

But it is affecting both `TextArea`s.

Also what is the background color of the disabled `TextArea` in JavaFX and how can I modify it?

```
TextArea textarea = new TextArea();
TextArea textarea1 = new TextArea();
```

These are the attributes I have applied

```
 textarea1.setMaxHeight(180);
 textarea1.setMaxWidth(500);
 textarea.setEditable(false);
 textarea.setPrefRowCount(15);
 textarea.setWrapText(true);
 textarea.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
 textarea1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: tomato");
```

Comment: I'm really sorry. I've searched far and wide and can't find anything with the way you're adding them. If you were using FXML my answer would suffice.

Comment: Thank you very much @SamOrozco for your help this far. But first i got to do basic stuff before going to fxml. So that's why I'm sticking to javafx and css. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

You can introduce a custom variable in CSS to determine the color.

When a `TextArea` is disabled, the opacity of the `TextArea` and children is set to `0.4` (=40%). You can undo this by overwriting the property in your stylesheet, if you wish.

```css
.text-area {
    /* use variable as inner background */
    -fx-control-inner-background: content-background;
}

/* keep element fully opaque, when disabled */
.text-area:disabled,
.text-area *:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}

/* replace inner background with darker color, when disabled */
.text-area:disabled {
    -fx-control-inner-background: derive(content-background, -40%);
}
```

```
// set content-background from inline style
textarea.setStyle("content-background: transparent;");
textarea1.setStyle("content-background: tomato;");
```

---

In case you do not need the color to determine the `-fx-control-inner-background` based on your chosen color (the `derive` part), you could also simply assign the property from inline style. In this case you do not need the CSS rules for the background in your stylesheet.

```
textarea.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: transparent;");
textarea1.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: tomato;");
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you need to do is put this line inside your css page:

```
.text-area .content {
    -fx-background-color: text-area-background ;
}
```

So now whatever you set your text-area background to it will set the content back grounf to that. So you should be able to do this below and it will work:

```
TextArea one = new TextArea();
        TextArea two = new TextArea();
        TextArea three = new TextArea();

        one.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
        two.setStyle("-fx-background-color: tomato");
        three.setStyle("-fx-background-color: steelblue");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,/

Comment: I tried that. but the contents inside remained unchanged

Comment: Only Border Color of text area is Changing

Comment: Help me to change the background of the content of textarea

Comment: Ok Let me try now

Comment: WARNING: Could not resolve 'text-area-background' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color' from rule '*.text-area *.content' in stylesheet

Comment: I got a warning like this and same output - Border color changed

Comment: Edit your question to show how you're creating the text areas

Comment: Sure. Give me a minute